# Xcode png image reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have made a project in xcode 3.2 after some time i upgraded my xcode in 4.2 every thing works fine. now i want to set up my project on another mac laptop having same environment. but during build it give me an error ie

> CpResource ../../Desktop/th_text-field.png error: /Users/gchauhan/Documents/project backup/30july/lisnxios_lisnxios/Lisnx/../../Desktop/th_text-field.png: No such file or directory

while this th_text-field.png is not present in my xcode project. i don't how it is happening please some one way out of me from this problem. i will highly thankful

Comment: Check your what files you are copying in your project (under build phases). Is the image there (with a red name)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: you are right those images is there with red name.So what should i do with them should i remove them..?

Comment: If you are still using it in your project then you should find it and add it again, otherwise you can remove it. It is failing because it can't find the image to copy it into your application bundle when you are building your project.

Comment: It also helped me to do a Project > Clean

Answer (score 2):

In you 3.2 project you must have added a referece of this png but not copied.

 Remove reference and then add again now make sure `copy item into destination ...` is checked like below

[image]

Comment: actually that image is not in my xcode project directory. how i can remove reference of that png file. but still i tried to put the images on the desk top and then build it but same problem....

Answer (score 1):

Thats normal. That image does not exist on other computer, so program can't find it. Always add images to your project bundle, so that it could work normally at other computers. I think even if you would add sandbox to your app it couldn't access image if he is in other directory, such as desktop or something like that. Music, Movies, Pictures and Downloads folders are easily accessable easy after sandboxing. To access other directories is alot of work to deal with sandbox. And you will need it if you are going to submit your app to appstore. And now, if that file doesnt shows up in xcode project's files list, then just add image (drag and drop) to your project files list and in window witch pops up, put tick on "Copy items...." and be sure that in "Add to targets" your app is ticked.